# Using PyQt5 for SMTP module on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, smtp, pyqt5

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QLabel,QLineEdit,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import sys
class window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):
        self.text=QLabel("your username,password, target , message and subject(username is without @gmail.com. but write @gmail.com for target")
        self.user=QLineEdit()
        self.passw=QLineEdit()
        self.passw.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.target=QLineEdit()
        self.message=QLineEdit()
        self.subject=QLineEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton("Send")

        v_box=QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.user)
        v_box.addWidget(self.passw)
        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addWidget(self.target)
        v_box.addWidget(self.message)
        v_box.addWidget(self.subject)
        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addWidget(self.button)
        v_box.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Deneme")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.func(self.user,self.passw,self.target,self.message,self.subject))


        self.show()

    def func(self,user,passw,target,message,subject):
        mes=MIMEMultipart()
        mes["From"]="Me"
        mes["To"]=target
        mes["Subject"] = subject

        body=MIMEText(message,"plain")
        mes.attach(body)

        try:
            mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login(user,passw)
            mail.sendmail(mes["from"],mes["To"],mes.as_string())
            mail.close()
        except:
            sys.stderr.write("Failed....")
            sys.stderr.flush()



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

objectt=window()


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when I run this code and click the button window is closing without sending the mail.

And I got this :Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Execute it from the cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `text()` method:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import sys


class window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.text = QLabel(
            "your username,password, target , message and subject(username is without @gmail.com. but write @gmail.com for target")
        self.user = QLineEdit()
        self.passw = QLineEdit()
        self.passw.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.target = QLineEdit()
        self.message = QLineEdit()
        self.subject = QLineEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton("Send")

        v_box = QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.user)
        v_box.addWidget(self.passw)
        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addWidget(self.target)
        v_box.addWidget(self.message)
        v_box.addWidget(self.subject)
        v_box.addStretch()
        v_box.addWidget(self.button)
        v_box.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Deneme")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.func(
            self.user, self.passw, self.target, self.message, self.subject))

        self.show()

    def func(self, user, passw, target, message, subject):
        mes = MIMEMultipart()
        mes["From"] = "Me"
        mes["To"] = target.text()
        mes["Subject"] = subject.text()

        body = MIMEText(message.text(), "plain")
        mes.attach(body)

        try:
            mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login(user.text(), passw.text())
            mail.sendmail(mes["from"], mes["To"], mes.as_string())
            mail.close()
        except:
            sys.stderr.write("Failed....")
            sys.stderr.flush()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

objectt = window()


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```